# Meaning of "ためし" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 驚くことはないよ、私なんか彼女が理解できたためしはない。

What i understand is : "It is not surprising! I, somehow, am unable to understand her" ?

The only 2 "ためし" i found are : 試し. trial; test​ and 例. precedent; example​
But i can't see what it would mean..

Thanks everyone !

Comment: context please?

Comment: `The answer here : ^ Eiríkr さんの訳があってるでしょうね・・・...` -- Could you tell us, if you don't mind, why you chose to accept the answer that provided an incorrect translation/interpretation, rather than the other answer with a correct translation/interpretation?

Comment: Oh wow, i misread your answer : She has never understood me **じゃなくて** I've never understood her myself **って意味でしょうね**、フツーは。。 

Btw what does : " 、フツーは。。 " means?

Thanks, and sorry for my mistake.

Comment: 「フツーは」, or 「普通は」, means "normally", "usually", or "generally"... I think. It's similar in meaning to 「通常は」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another ためし that fits here.  Etymology from Shogakukan's 国語大辞典:

> ためし【例・様】
>   （「た」は「手」で手本、「めし」は見せるものの意という）

Definitions and pitch accent from Daijirin:

> ためし [3] 【例・様】
>   （１）それより以前に実際にあった事柄。れい。先例。前例。「そのような―はない」
>   （２）手本となること。また，故事。「老たる馬ぞ道はしる，と云―あり/平家 9」

This has the same pitch accent as 試し, so verbally and in kana, you'll just have to know both terms and figure it out from context.

Since ためし in the sample sentence would mean "past instance of something", and since there aren't any past instances of 理解できた, a better translation might be:

> That is not surprising. I <s>do not always understand</s> **have never understood** her myself.

Comment: so, literally translated it would be "I don't have any examples of having ever understood her, either."   ... It must be a very "literary" form of speech?

Comment: "hisao m" said it was "*She* has never understood *me*." 
Which one is the correct one?

Comment: ^ Eiríkr さんの訳があってるでしょうね・・・　「驚くことはないよ、私なんか彼女が理解できたためしはない。」っていったら、 She has never understood me じゃなくて I've never understood her myself って意味でしょうね、フツーは。。

Answer (score 0):

According to  the dictionary, ためし  can be translated as "example", "precedent", "case"

Examples:
女性がそのような場所に行ったためしがあるだろうか
Has a woman ever visited such a place?

彼は競走に勝ったためしがない
He has never once won a race.

けんかで勝ったためしがない
I have never won a fight.

So the translation becomes:
私なんか彼女が理解できたためしはない。
She has never understood me.

ためし【例／様】: 前にすでにあったこと。先例。前例。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/例/#je-46730](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%BE%8B/#je-46730)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/139035/meaning/m1u/例/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/139035/meaning/m1u/%E4%BE%8B/)

Comment: どこからどこまでが引用ですか？　引用箇所は、わかるようにblockquoteに入れてください。